# USB thinks it a dvd/cd rom

Tags: windows-10, usb, usb-flash-drive, dvd, tv

I have a USB with movies on it. It worked perfectly before.

Now if I plug it in to my TV it says there is a problem with the USB so I plugged it in into my computer.

It doesn't have the icon it normally has - here is a screen shot the name of the USB is YENTE

[image: picture]

I opened the properties tab and there was something weird too. On the hardware tab there is disk station called ATTAPI iHOS104 and its type is dvd/cd-rom:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: What's the make and model of the USB flash drive?

Comment: Its 64 G from the company lexar

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not sufficient. Lexar makes many different 64GB drives and they have a variety of different ways of triggering autorun, which is the thing you're trying to disable. Do you know the actual model?

Comment: No the exact model i dont know what i want that my usb works again with my tv like my first screenshot you can see the i con of it is a yelow disk i dont know why he does that but there is somthin g. With my usb and now i cant use it on my tv

Comment: You can try backing it up (if it has data you care about) and then using a raw format utility. But it's hard to predict the result without knowing the exact model you have.

Comment: I already reformated ot once dont inow or thatvis the same as raw format but the reformat did not work

Comment: What tool did you use to format it? (And if you selected format from the windows drive manager, you didn't format the flash drive, you formatted the partition, which is *not* the same thing.)

Comment: Oww i used that obe from windowse can u please send somz programs then

Comment: Punch "usb flash low level format" into your favorite search engine.

Comment: i did it used a tool but it did not work